# JavaScript converted FILETIME is one day off

Tags: javascript, filetime

I have been reading about the JavaScript 'off-by-one' for dates, but I cannot figure out how to implement it in this situation.  I'm converting some values from an Internet Explorer cookie into a Microsoft FILETIME, but it's always ahead by one day, the code is:

```
function ConvertToFiletime(high, low) {
    var seconds = 1e-7 * (high * Math.pow(2, 32) + low) - 11644473600;
    var date = new Date.UTC(1970,1,1);
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + seconds);
    return date;
}
```

This does the conversion perfectly well, but I can't work out the best way to deal with the extra day, which I believe is due to a lack of a timezone.  Do I need to subtract a day's worth of seconds?  Or is there a better way.

Comment: You should always use the UTC methods to avoid timezone issues, only use the non UTC methods when displaying the time

Comment: Why don't you just use milliseconds? new Date(seconds*1000)

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but `Date.UTC(1970, 1, 1) ` is February 1st. You probably want `Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1)` for January 1st.

Comment: Clint, that totally was the problem!  Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
var date = new Date.UTC(1970,1,1);
```

`Date.UTC(1970, 1, 1)` is actually February 1st because month indexing starts at 0. You most likely want `Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1)` which is January 1st.

Also, `new Date.UTC()` throws an error for me on the latest version of Chrome and IE 11. To properly create a date object use:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks Clint, that solved that.  I was so busy looking at the strange JavaScript date behaviour that I overlooked that silly bit :)